# add content to dynamically generated item in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm generating dynamic list item by using the user given array values like below

```
var li_normal_item=$('#drop1').append("<li id='"+options.items[i].id+"'>"+options.items[i].value+"</li>")
```

Suppose, it generates something like below

```
<li id="ex">example</li>
```

now i want to add content to that li item in jQuery some thing like below

```
<li id="ex">example  <b>Basic QUestion</b> </li>
```

I tried like below, but it is adding after

```
li_normal_item.append("<b>Basic Example</b>")
```

How to do this in jQuery?

Comment: `li_normal_item` is `$('#drop1')` so try this `li_normal_item.find('li').append('<b>Basic Example</b>')`

Answer (score 1):

`append` method returns the current collection not the appended elements ie `li_normal_item` contains the `#drop1` element, you can reverse the logic using `appendTo` method:

```
var li_normal_item = $("<li>...</li>").appendTo('#drop1');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('<li>', {
   id: options.items[i].id,
   html: options.items[i].value
}).append(
   '<b> Basic Example</b>'
).appendTo('#drop1');
```

or if you want to append content later

```
li_normal_item = $('<li>', {
   id: options.items[i].id,
   html: options.items[i].value
}).appendTo('#drop1');

//append more
li_normal_item.append('<b> Basic Example</b>');
```